# Convert a browser Blob to Json

Tags: json, angular, typescript

The origin file is uploaded on Azure blob storage as a JSON data type, but when I create a readable stream to download the blob, I convert it as a string.

But now I figure it out that I need it as JSON, how do I edit this function, so the downloaded blob is a JSON file?

**jsondata.service.ts**

```
 async function blobToString(blob: Blob): Promise<string> {
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          fileReader.onloadend = (ev: any) => {
            resolve(ev.target!.result);
          };
          fileReader.onerror = reject;
    
    
          fileReader.readAsText(blob);
    
    
        });
      }
```

Comment: Can't you just parse it with `JSON.parse(textReadFromFileReader)` ?

Comment: @pascalpuetz what is textReadFromFileReader?

Comment: @teddy1995 its a peudo variable name. He is trying to tell you that you short parse the TEXT that has been READ FROM the FILE READER